# OpenVR direct mode prevent stand by mode

Tags: c++, steamvr, openvr, nvapi

Currently I am using "vr::IVRDriverDirectModeComponent" for my driver and I have no tracking device at the moment. I simulate the vr environment via giving monitor manufacturer and product id for the Display/Direct mode.

Due to there is no tracking device yet I would like to prevent the standby mode interferring during testing. I have tried offsetting the pose by minimal amounts but the result is not satisfactory.

Any direction would be appreciated.